# RoR call prompt in rjs

Tags: ruby-on-rails

in javascript i can call prompt like this
         var retVal = prompt("Enter the new first name : ");

how can i call same prompt in rjs file

i used,  page.prompt("Enter the new first name : ")

and its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
page << "prompt('Enter the new first name:');"
```

Comment: how can i get the value entered in text box

i used,  value = page << "prompt('Enter the new first name:');"
         page.alert(value)

i dont get the value

Comment: `page << "var response = prompt('Enter the new first name:');"` then you can do `page << "alert(response);"`